# When and how is /data mounted?

Tags: boot, partitions

I am exploring a bit on my Android device and I can't seem to figure out when `/data` is mounted.

My first guess what it'd be in `/init.rc`, and while that file creates the /data directory, it doesn't seem to actually mount it. I've also taken a look in `/system/etc/init.d`, but going from the files there, `/data` is already mounted at that point.

When is `/data` mounted, and where can I find the related script?